# Installing wordpress to VM locally /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php file

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine

so I am installing wordpress locally following https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress in KVM/Qemu, when I get to stage 5 "configuring wordpress from the browser" where you set the site title username and password I get an error...

cannot find /etc/wordpress/config-192.168.122.54.php

But I know the file is actually named...

/etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php

So I copy the file config-localhost.php to config-192.168.122.54.php in the same directory and it takes me to page I expected to land on, to configure wordpress.

My question is should I proceed knowing the IP will change due to DHCP or is there a simpler solution. My VM network Interface is "Virtual Network 'default': NAT" if this matters?

I know this is a hack and probably will break but does anyone know the correct solution, why is it expecting me to connect from 'localhost' URI and not allowing me to connect remotely to the VM. Why is it taking the address from the URL to search for the file on the server??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save yourself a bunch of hassle by making a symbolic link :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php /etc/wordpress/config-default.php
```

WordPress will always use the `config-default.php` file if it cannot find an IP or domain-based `.php` file.